# Secure db queries in single page web app

Tags: javascript, security, graph-databases, arangodb

I'm creating single page web app with ArangoDB for storage. Arango provides awesome ways for accessing and manipulating data. One of them is classic JS API. It would be easy to write straightforward DB queries in client side JS which would be direct queries for DB. So no server application in middle.

Of course, this is really unsecure pattern. So I should write some sort of REST-full API service that queries data from server via URL and later server queries the DB. But this is really inconvenient, since I'd need to write two or three times more code (first query for my server, second query for DB, and perhaps some translator between the two queries). Also, I think that API calls for my server would look almost same as API calls for DB.

I don't want to go for full abstraction since the app should be complex and there would be a lot of types of API request, which would only bring bugs and eat more time.

So what is the best way for requesting data in client app from DB in terms of, firstly, security and, secondly, ease of coding?

Comment: It seems you have conflicting goals. It's very easy to write insecure code. It's difficult to write secure code. But you want both. I think you should prefer security. Otherwise, you'll wish you had after your database gets dropped by means of SQL injection.

Comment: If you're targeting ArangoDB (seems so when looking at this question's tags), there is [Foxx](https://www.arangodb.com/foxx/). It's a server-side JavaScript framework for building REST-based applications, running inside ArangoDB. The database operations and queries your app needs can be made accessible via URLs so your single page app can call them directly. Still you have control over what queries can be run because you have control over the code inside the Foxx routes. There's no need to write client-side queries with Foxx, just the server URLs need to be called using regular AJAX means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a [GraphQL](http://graphql.org/) with [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) by Facebook which solves this problem best.

Comment: Yes, there a few more client-based DB. This way the Relay will call your web (REST) services and you need to implement proper authorization on the server-side services anyway.

Comment: Nope, with ArangoDB it's much more simple.No need for REST endpoints.

Comment: I understand your search for the usage simplicity and I don't say you need REST services at all. What I'm trying to say (check the original question) is, that without proper server-side authorization you cannot trust your client requests. It is always possible to manipulate / fake the client-side code.

Comment: Of course there is always need to check whether user which is trying to access or manipulate som object is allowed to do so. This should be done, I belive, through sessions and checking in Arango's foxx services.

Answer (score 1):

I'd really suggest to write REST API calls (or generally URL calls) to access your data. Anything what run on the client side or any traffic from the client can be accessed and manipulated. That comes with authentication and SQL calls themselves. 
What you want to secure? DB client authentication? If you encrypt it, you need to decrypt it on the client side. SQL calls - if you build and transmit them, the client could manipulate them to get / update ANY data with ANY values. Really no easy way around..
So - to be safe - stick to the patterns here..